# Using mysql with asterisk

Tags: mysql, asterisk

I have installed asterisk 11 on my centos 6 ,now i want to connect my asterisk with database
I am following [this](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/managing_databases.html) .I have both installed and configured mysql

I have created an outbound call (b.call)

```
Channel: DAHDI/g0/09********
MaxRetries: 1
RetryTime: 60
WaitTime: 30
Context: out
Extension: 47******
Priority: 1
```

and a simple dialplan(extensions.conf)

```
[out]
exten => 47*****,1,NoOp(<-------IVR----------->)
same => n,dial(DAHDI/g0/09********)
same => n,MYSQL(Connect connid localhost username pass dbname)
same => n,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} INSERT INTO `emp` (`name`) VALUES ('Akash'))
```

My problem is that,first 2 lines of dialplan executes perfectly but database lines are not executed,cli shows only first 2 lines executed and  last 2 lines not executed.

Am i missing any configuration settings??

Thanks

Comment: please check if you have MYSQL module installed for asterisk or not.

Comment: @nj thanks for replying,yes i have installed the mysql module from asterisk-addons

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802631/execute-dialplan-context-from-command-line

Comment: What errors are displayed on the console when you call that extension and those lines of code are processed by Asterisk?  Without that information, it's going to be just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likly you have no app_mysql loaded.

I higly not recommend use outdated mysql app. Use instead function REALTIME and func_ODBC.